# How to apply GPUImageMaskFilter on GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter for GPUImageVideoCamera

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I am trying to apply GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter to live camera feed masking with a PNG image. Also i need to mention that PNG image is not a square or circle but a closed Bezier Path.

Here is my code :

```
GPUImageVideoCamera *videoCamera;
GPUImageView *view1;

videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
CGRect movieFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 640.0, 480.0);

view1 = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:movieFrame];
[self.view addSubview:view1];

GPUImageMaskFilter * maskFilter = [[GPUImageMaskFilter alloc] init];

[videoCamera addTarget:maskFilter];

GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * gaussianBlurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
[gaussianBlurFilter setBlurRadiusInPixels:3.0];
[gaussianBlurFilter addTarget:maskFilter];

GPUImagePicture * maskGPUImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask2"] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
[maskGPUImage addTarget:maskFilter];
[maskGPUImage processImage];

[maskFilter addTarget:view1];

[videoCamera startCameraCapture];
```

But Xcode 6.0.1 breaks execution after compile in "GPUImageFramebuffer.m" on line :

```
NSAssert(framebufferReferenceCount > 0, @"Tried to overrelease a framebuffer, did you forget to call -useNextFrameForImageCapture before using -imageFromCurrentFramebuffer?");
```

Using OSX Mavericks 10.9.5, iPad Air for testing

Regards

Comment: with this code i just get black square in video view, but no error :  
`maskFilter = [[GPUImageMaskFilter alloc] init];`  
`[videoCamera addTarget:maskFilter];`  
`maskGPUImage = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mask2"] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];`  
`[maskGPUImage addTarget:maskFilter];`  
`[maskGPUImage processImage];`  
`gaussianBlurFilter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];`  
`[gaussianBlurFilter setBlurRadiusInPixels:0.8];`  
`[maskFilter addTarget:gaussianBlurFilter];`  
`[gaussianBlurFilter addTarget:view1];`  
`[videoCamera startCameraCapture];`

Comment: also made 3 variables global :  
    `GPUImageMaskFilter * maskFilter;`  
    `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * gaussianBlurFilter;`  
    `GPUImagePicture * maskGPUImage;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution; the references should be strong. Weak references are released early